# What is this code doing? Machine Learning

Tags: matlab

I'm just learning matlab and I have a snippet of code which I don't understand the syntax of. The x is an n x 1 vector.

Code is below

```
p  = (min(x):(max(x)/300):max(x))';
```

The p vector is used a few lines later to plot the function

```
plot(p,pp*model,'r');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generates an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

An arithmetic progression is a sequence of numbers where the next number is equal to the previous number plus a constant. In an arithmetic progression, this constant must stay the same value.

In your code,

- `min(x)` is the initial value of the sequence
- `max(x) / 300` is the increment amount
- `max(x)` is the stopping criteria. When the result of incrementation exceeds this stopping criteria, no more items are generated for the sequence.

I cannot comment on this particular choice of initial value and increment amount, without seeing the surrounding code where it was used.

However, from a naive perspective, MATLAB has a [`linspace` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) which does something similar, but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly looks to me like an odd thing to be doing. Basically, it's creating a vector of values `p` that range from the smallest to the largest values of `x`, which is fine, but it's using steps between successive values of `max(x)/300`.

If `min(x)=300` and `max(x)=300.5` then this would only give 1 point for `p`.

On the other hand, if `min(x)=-1000` and `max(x)=0.3` then `p` would have thousands of elements.

In fact, it's even worse. If `max(x)` is negative, then you would get an error as `p` would start from `min(x)`, some negative number below `max(x)`, and then each element would be smaller than the last.

I think `p` must be used to create `pp` or `model` somehow as well so that the plot works, and without knowing how I can't suggest how to fix this, but I can't think of a good reason why it would be done like this. using `linspace(min(x),max(x),300)` or setting the step to `(max(x)-min(x))/299` would make more sense to me.

Comment: yea i think the person who wrote the code probably meant to do linspace, but doesn't know about linspace.  then went on to assume that min(x)=0.

Answer (score 0):

This code examines an array named `x`, and finds its minimum value `min(x)` and its maximum value `max(x)`.  It takes the maximum value and divides it by the constant 300.

It doesn't explicitly name any variable, setting it equal to `max(x)/300`, but for the sake of explanation, I'm naming it "incr", short for increment.

And, it creates a vector named `p`. `p` looks something like this:

```
p = [min(x), min(x) + incr, min(x) + 2*incr, ..., min(x) + 299*incr, max(x)];
```

Comment: `p` is in no way guaranteed to have 300 elements, because `max(x)/300` could be larger than `max(x)-min(x)`. If the increment was `(max(x)-min(x))/300` then you would get 301 elements.